# How to populate the value from array of Objectid?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm Populating array of objects i don't know how i didn't get the result ?

Here my Schema for Todo model Each todo can have multiple collaborators

```
   collaborators: [{

        collaborator: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Users'
        }
    }]
```

the code doing the populate

```
const task = await Todo.find().populate('collaborators.collaborator').exec()
```

and i expected this query will give the todo info and all collobarotor info as well but only it give as a todo info only

Result i get

```
[
   {
     _id: 5eb672eb197e5d1afca21a23,
     title: 'testing colla',
     todo_description: 'paptefhfbjebjfbhjebfa.m',
     priority: 'Low',
     duedate: 2020-05-09T09:07:30.000Z,
     image: [ [Object] ],
     status: 'In Progress',
     userid: 5e900762314fd13148cd3393,
     assignee: 'nikil',
     collaborators: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0
   }
]
```

Comment: can you console.log(task.collaborators[0].collaborator) and post the output

Comment: hi adhi i'm getting when i logged the data  `5e900762314fd13148cd3393`